# wget download not completing all pages

Tags: linux, bash, curl, for-loop, wget

I need to download over 30k pages on Linux and imagined I could do that with a simple bash script + wget, here is what I came up with:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_time=$(date +%s)
for i in {1..30802}
do
        echo "Downloading page http://www.domain.com/page:$i"
        wget "http://www.domain.com/page:$i" -q -o /dev/null -b -O pages/$i
        running=$(ps -ef | grep wget | wc -l)
        while [ $running -gt 1000 ]
        do
                running=$(ps -ef | grep wget | wc -l)
                echo "Current running $running process."
                sleep 1;
        done
done

while [ $running -gt 1 ]
do
        running=$(ps -ef | grep wget | wc -l)
        echo "Waiting for all the process to end..."
        sleep 10;
done

finish_time=$(date +%s)
echo "Time duration: $((finish_time - start_time)) secs."
```

**Some pages are not being completely downloaded!**

- Since the above code will make 1k wget parallel running process and
  wait until it lowers to add more process, could it be that I am
  actually exhausting all the available internet link ?
- How could I make this more reliable to make sure the page is actually
  being properly downloaded ?

**EDIT:**

- I heard that curl is a better option for downloading pages is that
  true ?

Comment: 1k concurrent connections might be over doing it a bit... also you are not checking the return code from wget...

Comment: Agree with Scottymac. Do you have the same problem if you go w 100 concurrent connections? Good luck.

Comment: @Scottymac, shellter thanks for pointing that out I also agree that I may be overdoing it, but I need it to be able to get all the pages within 3 hours top which is why I am looking for a way to optimize or some reliable way to do this with a bash script + whatever is available on Linux. With 1k process it takes 2 hours and 21 minutes currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solution to your situation:

1) Change the way you call `wget` to something like this:

```
(wget "http://www.domain.com/page:$i" -q -o /dev/null -O pages/$i || touch $i.bad) &
```

2) When your script finishes, search for all `*.bad` files and relaunch the `wget` for each of them. Delete the corresponding `.bad` file before the new retry.

3) Do until no `*.bad` file exists.

That's the general idea. Hope that helped!

**EDIT:**

For the situation in which `wget` processes disappear, are killed or end abruptly, there is a possible refinement:

```
(wget "http://www.domain.com/page:$i" -q -o /dev/null -O pages/$i || touch $i.bad && touch $i.ok) &
```

Then you can analyze if some page has been downloaded completely or `wget` failed to end.

**EDIT 2:**

After some testings and digging, I've discovered that my former proposal was **flawed**. The order of the conditionals **must be interchanged**:

```
(wget "http://www.domain.com/page:$i" -q -o /dev/null -O pages/$i && touch $i.ok || touch $i.bad) &
```

So,

- If the download is executed correctly by `wget` (i.e. it finished with an OK return code) then there must be two files: the downloaded page and the `.ok` file.
- If the download fails (i.e. `wget` returns a KO return code), then there must be the `.bad` file, and perhaps a partial download of the page.

In any case, only the `.ok` files are significant: they say that the download was finished correctly (from the `wget` point of view, and I will discuss this later).

If no `.ok` file is found for an specific page, then surely it has not been downloaded, so it must be retried.

Then, we get to the most delicate part of your procedure: what happens if a web server, as a response to that big number of requests, cancels those he cannot serve with an HTTP 200 response and a zero content length? That would be a good technique to avoid web copying or some kind of server attack.

If that's the case, you must take a look at the pattern of the responses. There will be an `.ok` file, but perhaps the file size of the downloaded page will be zero.

You can detect those *zero-length downloads* with:

```
filesize=$(cat $i.html | wc -c)
```

And then add some logic to the former procedure of `.ok` and `.bad` files:

```
retry=0
if [ -f $i.bad ]
then
  retry=1
elif [ -f $i.ok ]
then
  if [ $filesize -eq 0 ]
  then
    retry=1
  fi
else
  retry=1
fi

if [ $retry -eq 1 ]
then
  # retry the download
fi
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Very nice answer but the problem is the bad files also have html content and they are not originated of a error such as 500 or 404, so how would it be able to identify one was bad or not ?

Comment: If wget finishes with a "OK", then you must `grep` or something the files searching for the possible erroneous files, but I don't understand in which cases you will have an "OK" from `wget` and be an erroneous download...

Comment: If the problem is in terms of `wget` processes being killed or cancelled abruptly, you can modify the algorithm by executing '`(wget "http://www.domain.com/page:$i" -q -o /dev/null -O pages/$i || touch $i.bad && touch $i.ok) &` If no ok file, also retry.

Comment: I just ran your code and it is creating 2 files a bad one and the page one both 0 lengthed. Same goes for the 2nd sample generate 3 empty files.

Comment: have you deleted the `-b` switch?

Comment: yes I have, I was trying the command exactly the way you posted, you could even say I simple copy and pasted it into the code and removed my method.

Comment: I'm lost, the proposed command line *should* work! I'll take a look at it as soon as I can.

Comment: @FèlixGalindoAllué thank you I will try it now and let u know how it goes but really appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what kind of connection you have, high number of current connections leads to packet loss. Also consider what kind of connection the server has. If this is not an in-house server, the party that hosts the server might think this is a denial of service attack and filter your IP. It is more reliable just do it one by one. The bottle neck is almost always the internet connection, you can't do it any faster.

Comment: Server is mine its a 1GigE port/link on the server and a 20Mbps connection at my end.

Comment: Then there isn't much benefit by parallellizing it. All the processes you spawned will be waiting for packets. Some packets will drop and you have to do more and more retries which worsen the situation.